# SQLDataSource FilterExpression DataView - Cannot find column [myColumn]

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sqldatasource

I'm trying to do a SQLDataSource.FilterExpression as follows:

```
SqlDataSource view = new SqlDataSource(){ID = "view"};
    this.Page.Controls.Add(view);
    view.ConnectionString = ConnectionBDD.BDD;
    view.SelectCommand = tempReq;
    if (dpl_typTdb.SelectedValue != "Tout")
    {
        view.FilterExpression = "c.typTdb LIKE '{0}'";
        view.FilterParameters.Add(new ControlParameter("typTdb", "dpl_typTdb", "SelectedValue"));
    }
    DataView dv = (DataView)view.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    if(dv.Count < 1)
    {
        //some code...
    }
```

My var tempReq looks like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM Cnd c
LEFT JOIN typCndAct a 
    ON c.TpCndAct = a.TpCndAct
LEFT JOIN typCndPrr p 
    ON c.TpCndPrr = p.TpCndPrr
ORDER BY c.MdfLe DESC
```

Then, I got a throw exception like it:

"Cannot find column [c.typTdb]."

And I'm sure this column is in my table,

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Try giving just typTdb instead of c.typTdb?

Comment: Can you show us the final SELECT?

Comment: Adil, yes I try it but I got the same throw exception.

Comment: jarlh, how to get the query after FilterExpression?